# docker is not running as rootless

Tags: docker, arch

i had install docker on arch Manjaro
had try
`sudo usermod -aG docker $USER`
it is added to the user

```
id arch 
uid=1000(arch) gid=1001(arch) groups=1001(arch),998(wheel),991(lp),3(sys),90(network),98(power),1000(autologin),962(docker)
```

```
docker ps
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///home/arch/.docker/desktop/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

*i have to edit a file that present in docker but iam not able to *

Comment: It appears the docker daemon is not running?

Comment: how to run docker demon bez `sudo docker ps `works

Comment: What does bez mean?

Comment: haha bez->because

Comment: How about `sudo systemctl start docker.service`? Like in the very first section in https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/docker described?

Comment: This question is asking about Docker's rootless mode. `sudo systemctl start docker.service` is **not** going to help; that's how you would start Docker in the regular root-required mode. Running `sudo docker ps` isn't a good test, either, because that `sudo` command means you're running `docker ps` as the `root` user.

Comment: There are instructions [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/) for how to start Docker in rootless mode. Have you followed these instructions? If things aren't working as expected, show us the exact commands you've used and explain how their behavior differs from what you expect.